# How can I Create Geo Log Entity for every login in of the User (systemuser)?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I want to create a record of Geo Log entity for every login of the user in CRM. So, I want to take the IP Address, Browser, Operation system, Longitude, Latitude, ect. for every login of the user in the system. I want to do this in the Server side, but I am facing problems for creating a plugin for triggering the event of login of the user.

Comment: The data points you are trying to collect are inherently client side, and as established in your previous question, you will not be able to trigger a plugin on this action. You have this tagged as CRM online, if that is the case then I think this is going to be quite difficult or impossible. What you definitely could do is add scripts to a form onload action to collect this information.

Answer (score 0):

Like Zach mentioned, all these client side telemetry can be collected in JavaScript & created as a record in CRM entity using web api.

There’s no supported solution to inject the script in all forms when we don’t know where users are landing (after ADFS challenge/SSO user will land in their workspace tab based on their personal preference).

The trick is to force every user to land in a particular dashboard or entity view, adding JavaScript to any of the Ribbon button “Enable rule” to trigger & execute the snippet. You can use form load script on entity form or Application Ribbon (always visible button) too.

Server side - never mind. For your satisfaction you can do a custom Action to create data in entity & data can be passed from JavaScript to that custom Action as parameters.